# Unmanage all USB ethernet adapters, but keep names unique

Tags: linux, usb, ethernet, udev, networkmanager

One can disable a particular interface by listing it in one of the configs:

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:enx6c4bca1ac914

But I want ALL USB ethernet adapters to be unmanaged and do not want to go edit the config every time a new adapter is attached.

Is this possible within NetworkManager alone or I need some hackery?
It is possible to rename the interface via udev config, giving it a fixed name, like "usb" and then add it into the unmanaged config.
But I also want the interfaces to be different in order to identify particular devices in my network settings scripts.

Any idea if udev configs support some kind of concatenation of strings with which name generation could be achieved, e.g. "enx6c4bca1ac914" is renamed to "usb_enx6c4bca1ac914" ?

Comment: I think you can use `$kernel`/`%k` (prefixed with `usb_`) in `NAME=` of a udev rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using udev rules, just directly set `ENV{NM_UNMANAGED}="1"` for USB-based network interfaces. Current versions of NetworkManager will read this property, so there's no need to go the long way around by defining special interface names.

By default, systemd does not use the `enx`/`wlx` MAC-address-based naming for anything – Debian and Ubuntu have their custom udev rules that enable this name format *only* for USB interfaces. So unless you've explicitly enabled the MAC-based name style for other interface types, you could just match `enx*`.

As documented, current versions of NetworkManager also have several more "interface match" formats beyond just `interface-name:` (see "Device List Format" in the manpage). Out of those, `driver:` would be relevant if all your USB adapters are of the same type – although you can't currently match "all USB devices" by bus or path:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=driver:cdc_ether;driver:rtl8192u;
```

The same can also be used in its "match-based" configuration sections, which work similarly to systemd-networkd's .network files (though, again, no bus or syspath based matching):

```
[device-usb]
match-device=driver:cdc_ether
managed=0
```